# Codeigniter website PHP code theme not working to register & Login

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I noticed that the login function and registration function is clearly not working and keeps giving an error, not giving the option to register nor login to the previous account registered on the database. Here is the code of `login.php` and `user.php`. The website uses CodeIgniter and that could be where the problem is I think.

Code for `login.php` in `JustWallet 2.0.4\application\views\user`:

```php
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<div class="header-st mb-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>
              <?php echo lang('core button sign_in') ?>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <?php echo form_open('', array('class'=>'')); ?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('core button username_email'); ?></label>
            <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'username', 'id'=>'username', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>lang('core button enter_username'), 'maxlength'=>256)); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><?php echo lang('core button password'); ?></label>
            <?php echo form_password(array('name'=>'password', 'id'=>'password', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>lang('core button enter_password'), 'maxlength'=>72, 'autocomplete'=>'off')); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $this->settings->google_site_key; ?>"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/forgot'); ?>"><?php echo lang('core button forgot'); ?></a></br>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url('user/register'); ?>"><?php echo lang('core button create'); ?></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo lang('core button login'); ?></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am getting these errors:

1. When using the correct login details from the database):

> Invalid username or password

2. When trying to login to an account that already exists in the database:

> Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(_check_login)

3. When trying to register a new account (even though that is a new account to be created):

> Your account could not be created at this time. Please try again.

[image: screenshot of the errors]

Here is an image of the existing account in the database and the whole database:
[image: image of the existing account in the database and the whole database]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `<?php form_open() ?>` still empty.
2. please provide your controller/method link inside form_open('controller/method',$parameter)
3. We couldn't see because u still don't provide your controller code.

My thoughts: You still have blank form_open. And Why are you use google recapthca?, I mean, you should check your "recaptcha" validation in your controller. This cannot be done until you have given the controller segment to this question.

**UPDATED**:

Hmm, I confused, why did u update a `Plain text` to your password here?

[image: why?]

Next this is under your login callback method inside `User.php`:

[image: Here what I found]

Red circle explanation:

1. Your password supposed to be hashed programmatically when the user create their account. When you validate it using callback `_check_login()` here, It might be verified with hash comparation under `password_verify()` function inside your model. Why did you do that? (updating the password manually with the plain text ? :D)
2. And this is my biggest question to you.. Did you know about google recaptcha before? Google recaptcha only work in hosted site not localhost. Are you using your own program, I mean your own recaptcha's site /secret key? well.. it seems you don't own this program. When you try to validate with another site/secret's key, you cannot continue (see here https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/), otherwise you have to delete every recaptcha validations in this program.

Comment: Here is all the folders that i have in my Controllers file which one you want the code of i will provide it all thanks for your answer by the way 
![image of Controllers File] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuujx.png)

Comment: @ReadytoMaster yup, there's a lot of controller file in the folder, but could you please give where's the signin or register controller in "codes". I mean line of codes. your controller codes. Maybe inside the `login.php` and `user.php` show us the specific method of controller there

Comment: Thanks for your reply a lot @Alfian Firmansyah here is the code of user.php that was found in \Just Wallet 2.0.4\application\controllers In this [link](https://justpaste.it/4vpir) the only login.php i have in website is already posted in original question

Comment: Friend @Alfian Firmansyah i just added the google recaptcha keys to the website and now the recaptcha is working fine and for the password plain text in phpmyadmin you mentioned i fixed it aswell now the password is a huge line of encrypted numbers, the only thing i didn't understand is how to fix the form is empty problem you said and this issue still remains (Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(_check_login)) Whilst Logging in and Registering Your account could not be created at this time. Please try again. Please Help What do i need to provide

Comment: Here are my website files if you can fix the problem in the code @Alfian Firmansyah i will be more then grateful here [link](https://filebin.net/archive/6zt6ivvy1z88npcv/zip?t=amlze71s)

Comment: Provide your db as well.

Comment: Friend @Alfian Firmansyah here is the whole website files including documentations and database please fix the wrong codes and provide me at end with working files of the website for me to use thanks a lot here [link](https://filebin.net/archive/xdcuxdnsb3sqnxap/zip?t=2m5oa7cv)

Comment: Friend @Alfian Firmansyah Did you install the whole files of the website with success are you working on fixing the wrong code in order to provide me at end with fixed files of website to use Thanks a lot for the help by the way :)

Comment: @ReadytoMaster yes I have, but I cannot fix it today, bcs have to work, I will fix it in my leisure time tho.

Comment: Ok @Alfian Firmansyah Really appreciated lets keep contact here :)

Comment: Friend @Alfian Firmansyah Once all the problems in the code of the website files are fixed just provide me with the installation link of all the files and Data Base fixed and working I will really appreciate the sooner the better you're the best thanks a lot friend

Comment: Good Morning Friend @Alfian Firmansyah any progress on the website files friend ?

Comment: Hi Friend @Alfian Firmansyah Please i am waiting on your reply :) will really appreciate it